# Plot Evolution of portfolio weights over time in R

Tags: equities, programming, portfolio-management, backtesting, r

Is there any function for plotting the evolution of portfolio weights over time in r?. I have a matrix of portfolio weights from an equal weighting strategy at rebalancing times and want to plot weights of the stocks  over time on a single plot.

for example:you want to backtest equal weight strategy where you allocate weights equally at each rebalancing dates for each stock. I have a matrix of weights:

```
             A       B            C       D              E           F
```

2001-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2002-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2003-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2004-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2005-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2006-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2007-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2008-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2009-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2010-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

2011-12-01 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806 0.03225806

I want to plot the stocks(A,B,..) on a single plot where the y axis will be the allocatons and x axis the time ie plotting a transition map for weights over time using R

Regards

Comment: Could you please provide more information like e.g. code, an example matrix with the weights etc.?

Comment: I think this is off-topic because in short you ask how to plot multvariate time series - right? Look at the xts package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html and get to know time formats in R.

Comment: This is a simple programming question.

Comment: Although the question has been closed you can still upvote my answer and accept it if it was helpful - Thank you :-)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure out what I really needed, I wanted stacked Area Graph to plot the weights over time. I used the ggplot after changing my time series object to long format.@vonjd

Comment: @user3481555: Great, that sounds good. Unfortunately you cannot post your answer because the question is closed. Anyway: It is considered good practice here to vote and accept helpful answers - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
W <- matrix(rep(0.03225806,66),nrow=11)
T <- seq(as.Date("2001-12-01"), as.Date("2011-12-01 "), "years")
M <- read.zoo(data.frame(T,W))
colnames(M) <- c(LETTERS[1:6])
plot.zoo(M)
plot.zoo(M,plot.type = "single")
```